# What is the easiest way to update thousands of users' "created date"?

Tags: users, views

I want to change all user created date. Is it possible use [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) for that? However, I don't see any option to change the user's created date there.

Originally the site is migrated from Joomla; I have thousands of users with a blank created date, and I want to set them to a week ago.
Can this be done with [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)?

Comment: Modify entity values field? I think you can use it (you will probably need to a UNIX timestamp)

Comment: @Ayesh K I did use the "Modify entity values" but there is no timestamp or created date. What do you mean by "need a Unix timestamp"? Do I need to add a new field on Account setting?

Comment: You can create Rules Component and run it from VBO for updating created field.

Comment: Do you want to give all users the same created date, or do you have a data source from which you want to import?

Comment: @marcvangend I wanna change them all to the same created date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that changing the created dates is a one-time action, and that other modules in your Drupal site do not need to react to the users being updated.

IMHO, if you're looking at modules to do this, you're making things way too complicated for yourself. A simple SQL query should to the job:

```
UPDATE users SET created = 1234567890 WHERE uid <> 0;
```

You can choose / [calculate](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) the timestamp yourself (where it says `1234567890` in my example). I'm excluding the record with user id 0 because this repesents the anonymous user who does not have a created date.

How to run this query:

- From a MySQL admin tool, like phpMyAdmin or HeidiSQL, whatever you have to access your database;
- From the command line using the mysql command (don't know if this works on Windows):

  ```
  $ mysql -u user_name -p -e 'UPDATE users SET created = 1234567890 WHERE uid <> 0' database_name
  ```
- From the command line using [Drush](http://www.drush.org/):

  ```
  $ drush sql-query "UPDATE users SET created = 1234567890 WHERE uid <> 0"
  ```

Comment: Ty marcvangend. This is something I'm looking for.